# Trouble using conio.h library

Tags: c++, codeblocks, conio

Am having trouble using the Conio library in my code blocks IDE while doing c++ code. Am using Windows 8.1. To be specific i need to use conio library functions for my c and c++ programs but the header file is not available.am looking for a link or address to download the library.

Comment: May I suggest you change lecturers, so that you get one that lectures about this, or at least the last before this, decade...

Comment: Check your spelling. The word is library not LIBRARY.

Comment: As an aside TDM-GCC 4.9.2 still has this header. So have you checked that your installation of CodeBlocks (which I guess has installed MinGW) does not have this header file?

Comment: `<conio.h>` is windows specific. I would avoid using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using MinGW you could download [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/conio/) implementation.

Comment: thanks so much @Raul am using MinGW the link led straight to download... it now working...